# moving js to separate file and including the file in html stops returning some data

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a view where I am returning some data I create in the controller, let's say an array of db rows. If I put the js to create boxes that use that data inside the html everything's fine. If I separate it to public/js and include the same exact script those data is not returned anymore. Is it because calling the file from outside doesn't grant access to the array I passed to the view? And if so how can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Check if the separate js file is actually loaded (browser debug Net tab) and included **before** you use it. Any errors, code snippet etc. to clarify 'data is not returned anymore'?

Comment: I think it's loaded as it partially works, meaning I get a result from the jquery call, the callback function draws my boxes with images etc but the data is not shown anymore in the form I expect, instead of the number 37 (for example) the script renders `{{ number_format($size->it,1) }}`

Comment: yes it's loaded but behaves badly

Comment: Aha. Looks like your script needs to be processed by a template engine. Hard to say without some code...

Comment: oh ok so it's blade that is not processing that strings, do you know how could I make it process?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with laravel/blade, but you could request a php file that processes your JS server side and then return that. However, you'll need a context to set up $size etc., which you probably already have in your main file. It's probably simplest to 'include' that JS in your PHP producing the HTML, unless you need it to be dynamic, i.e. AJAX etc?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comments, RE: processing Blade string in javascript.

There is a couple of options, one is to add them to the end of your current blade files in some script tags and add them from there. E.g.

```
... normal blade view stuff

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var size = {{ number_format($size->it,1) }};
   </script>
</body>
```

The other option would be to create a file in your views directory with the extension `script.js.blade.php` so that blade will render it, then in that file you could `@include('your-actual-script.js')` and it would then be parsed by blade. The only trouble with this is that the fake file would have the wrong response headers so you'd have to force them in your controller e.g.

```
$contents = View::make('script.js')->with('size', $size);
$response = Response::make($contents, 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
return $response;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem here is my controller doesn't return a view but a Json response. The callback function fills a div with a resultStr that fills the page by iterating through data (json response) and creates boxes for every item. What I need is to load the resultStr from a separate file once the data is ready instead of having all the script and resultStr encoded in the view.